# how to use analytical function for unordered list of values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

set up table and inserting data into it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST 

   (           ID NUMBER, 
               TECH VARCHAR2(200), 
               DAY_WID NUMBER
   );
 
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210428);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210412);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210402);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210415);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210408);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210430);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210414);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210427);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210422);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210426);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210419);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210401);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210413);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210429);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210406);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210416);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210420);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210409);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210421);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210407);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'EXCLUDE',20210405);
Insert into TEST (ID,TECH,DAY_WID) values (999,'INCLUDE',20210423);

select * from test order by day_wid
```

Now i need to create a day_wid_min and day_Wid_max  based on Tech column
as per the picture below Tech column values as "Exclude" is showing till day_wid 20210407

Please advise how to use the analytical function oracle to achieve the expected output mark in blue color

[image: expected output]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: Is TECH always `INCLUDE` or `EXCLUDE`?

Comment: Yes .. It will be always INCLUDE AND EXCLUDE

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical use case for [SQL for Pattern Matching](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/pattern.htm#DWHSG8956)

```
SELECT *
FROM TEST 
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    PARTITION BY ID
    ORDER BY DAY_WID
    MEASURES 
        FINAL MIN(DAY_WID) AS min_DAY_WID,
        FINAL MAX(DAY_WID) AS max_DAY_WID,
        MATCH_NUMBER() AS match_num,
        RUNNING COUNT(*) AS cnt_num
    ALL ROWS PER MATCH 
    PATTERN (a b*)
    DEFINE 
        a AS tech = NEXT(tech),
        b AS tech = PREV(tech)
);
```

Column `match_num` and `cnt_num` may be used for additional filtering, if required.

Comment: Thanks Wernfried Domscheit

Comment: HI Wernfried Domscheit, when i am providing one more id , it is not working .. it is working only for 999 id

Comment: Add `PARTITION BY ID` - see my updated answer.